# `Warning: Cannot parent components or objects in the underworld.` : adding bend deformer to group

Tags: python, maya

following lines lead to `Warning: Cannot parent components or objects in the underworld.`

self.lashesGroup = cmds.group(em=True, name="lashesGroup")
cmds.parent(self.benddeformer, self.lashesGroup)

benddeformer is a non-linear bend deformer - how can i avoid this warning? because it doesnt bother at first, but seems to cause problems later on

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to make sure that `benddeformer` is the transform which owns the deformer handle.  You can't parent non-dag nodes. However you can get the handle from the bend node like this:

```
handle = (cmds.listConnections(self.benddeformer + ".matrix") or [None])[0]
if handle:
   cmds.parent(handle, self.lashesGroup)
```